# Aggregation for join ON clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `item_table` like this:

```
item   age
--------------    
1      1 
1      6 
2      2
```

I have the other table `price_table` like this:

```
item    pricetype    price
--------------------------    
1       O             5
1       P             6
1       V             7
2       O             8
2       P             9
2       V             10
```

So, I want to inner join above two tables.

```
select *
from item_table i
inner join price_table p
on ...
```

There are some conditions about the `on`:

1. if **the average of age** of an item is bigger than `3`, then I do: `inner join price_table on pricetype = 'O' or pricetype = 'P'`
2. If not, then I do: `inner join price_table on pricetype = 'O' or pricetype = 'P' or pricetype = 'V'`

So there are conditions for `on` conditions.

I then write the query like this:

```
select i.item, i.type, p.pricetype, p.price
from item_table i
inner join price_table p on i.item = p.item 
    and (avg(i.age) >= 3 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P'))
        or (avg(i.age) < 3 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P', 'V'))
```

The error is given: `An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.`

I can't move the `avg` to `Having` because other conditions are depending on the `avg`.

**How can I write the select query?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select *
from (
    select item, avg(age) as AvgAge
    from item_table
    group by item
) ia
inner join price_table p on ia.item = p.item 
    and ((ia.AvgAge >= 3 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P'))
        or (ia.AvgAge < 3 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P', 'V')))
```

[SQL Fiddle Example 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4d08/11)

This can be simplified to:

```
select *
from (
    select item, avg(age) as AvgAge
    from item_table
    group by item
) ia
inner join price_table p on ia.item = p.item 
    and (p.pricetype in ('O', 'P')
        or (ia.AvgAge < 3 and p.pricetype = 'V'))
```

[SQL Fiddle Example 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4d08/12)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try placing the aggregation in a subquery, then you have the `avg()` value for use in the `JOIN` clause:

```
select i.item, i.type, p.pricetype, p.price
from
(
    select avg(i.age) age, i.item, i.type  -- not sure where type is coming from in your OP as it is not in the table you showed
    from item_table i
    group by i.item, i.type
)   i
inner join price_table p 
    on i.item = p.item 
    and ((i.age>= 3 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P'))
        or (i.age < 3 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P', 'V')))
```